# Android: On changing the image on ImageView the Edittext disappeared

Tags: android, button, imageview, android-relativelayout, android-edittext

I am new to android app development on eclipse IDE.

I am trying to make a basic app in which, on clicking the button both the image in ImageView as well as the text in EditText replaces with another image and text respectively.

But on doing so, primarily when the app starts, a button is displayed on the top, then the ImageView and then the EditText, they work fine, but on clicking the button, only image is replaced successfully while my EditText disappeared. Can you help me out why this happened and how to rectify it?

xml file:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/click_it" />



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:src="@drawable/prac" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="hello!" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

java file:

```
package com.example.practicetwo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button b1;
ImageView iv1;
EditText et1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1 = (Button)findViewById(new R.id().button1);
    iv1 = (ImageView)findViewById(new R.id().imageView1);
    et1 = (EditText)findViewById(new R.id().editText1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.prac1);
            et1.setText("how r u?");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: try accessing in a static way, like findViewById(R.id.editText1) instead new findViewById(R.id().editText1)

Comment: your image prac1 might be greater than the size of the screen, and as you replace prac with prac1 the `EditText`is pushed down. Try using 'LinearLayout' instead of relative layout.

Comment: on writing, et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id().editText1); it is showing errors.

Comment: @Naveen yes my prac1 image is greater tahn the prac image. and now using LinearLayout its working fine. i just need to do some more research on this. thanks by the way.

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer, you can accept it. If you need any more help, do let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image prac1 might be greater than the size of the screen, and as you replace prac with prac1 the `EditText` is pushed down. Try using `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: please tell me that can I set the visibility of these EditText and ImageView or not and how?

Comment: one more doubt... when i transferred this app to my sd card n tried to run through the android app "AIDE" it is showing an error "aapt:invalid resourse directory name:/mnt/sdcard/AppProjects/PracticeTwo/res/drawwable-xxhdpi" please tell me how to rectify it...its urgent.

Comment: you can always use `view.setVisibility(false)` for the visibility part and I think the xxhdpi might not be recognized by the device android version.

Comment: I just checked aide and I think it might not support xxhdpi folder, just a guess.

Comment: ok thanks...actually i was trying to create the apk using that app instead of copying it from the bin directory.